# Display a Web page on a TV channel with a PCMCIA card

Tags: smart-tv

I search a very simple way to display a Web page (with a photos slideshow) on my TV on a new channel (let's say channel 0).

Is is possible to program a PCMCIA to do that ? With a wifi or RJ45 connection.

Comment: I very much doubt it. If you want a simple way, then build an app and submit it to the app store for the TV. No need to involve hardware.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it on a channel, so my grandma can easily change the channel with the plus and minus buttons to see my photos. I know some DVB CI stuff can add overlay on channel, so I hope is it possible to do more